# How to open a window with a custom link?

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I have made an html website on my local storage. I also made a button, then a `href` attribute since I want to go to another link. What happens is I provide a link, then it just goes to an odd path and doesn't work. Check what I mean below:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('https://www.example.com', '_blank', 'width=200, height=100, menubar=0,titlebar=0,status=0')" target="_blank">Click Me!</a>
```

---

It simply just opens another window and contains an odd path through my files. I have tried searching up how to fix this. With my wordings I couldn't find an answer. I even tried looking for questions similar to this, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using windows.open you don't have to use a tag and, it will automatically open the link in a new tab so you don't need to use target="_blank".

Just do as following:

```
<a onclick="window.open('https://www.example.com')" >Click Me!</a>
```

or this without onclick:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">Click Me!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<input type="button" value="Open a Popup Window" onclick="window.open('https://www.example.com','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');">
```